# How to run a method from HC-Sticky plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hcsticky

I am using [HC-Sticky](https://github.com/somewebmedia/hc-sticky) JavaScript plugin and trying to use the [documented](https://github.com/somewebmedia/hc-sticky#methods) `reinit` method, but I don't understand how to run it.

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzavRw?editors=1111) showing a very basic setup and an attempt at running the `reinit` method right after the initialization, but the console always says that the

> reinit function is not defined

How you would normally run a method in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your HC-Sticky instance in a variable, then you can use HC-Sticky's API:

```
var sticky = new hcSticky('.this-sticks', {
    stickTo: 'main'
});    

sticky.reinit();
```

**OR** access it via `jQuery.data(...)`:

```
jQuery('.this-sticks').hcSticky({
    stickTo: 'main'
});

jQuery('.this-sticks').data('hcSticky').reinit();
```

---

## Example 1:

Using `new hcSticky(...)`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var sticky = new hcSticky('.this-sticks', {
    stickTo: 'main'

  });      
  sticky.reinit();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 300px;
}

header {
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
}

footer {
  height: 400px;
  background: black;
}

.this-sticks {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>HC Sticky Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <section class="this-sticks">sticky</section>
    <section></section>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>  
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/somewebmedia/hc-sticky/master/dist/hc-sticky.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

## Example 2:

Using `jQuery(...).hcSticky(...)`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.this-sticks').hcSticky({
    stickTo: 'main'
  });
  
  jQuery('.this-sticks').data('hcSticky').reinit();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 300px;
}

header {
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
}

footer {
  height: 400px;
  background: black;
}

.this-sticks {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>HC Sticky Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <section class="this-sticks">sticky</section>
    <section></section>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>  
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/somewebmedia/hc-sticky/master/dist/hc-sticky.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but it didn't work when I did it with jQuery. Are you implying that the API is only accessible if done in vanilla Javascript? Here is a codepen with how I tried that: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKZXqO?editors=1111

Comment: I updated my answer, to use via jQuery, use `.data(...)` to access HC-Sticky's API, like this: `jQuery('.this-sticks').data('hcSticky').reinit();`.